# Disable event click from component angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

I am working with the component on the link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/calendar/

I couldn't find any function or property that disables component state so I can't select dates on the calendar.

For this reason I would like to know if it is possible to remove the click event so that it cannot select dates in a given situation.

I can only disable the dates that he can't select, only that I can't display the selected dates that I manually entered in the schedule.

**Is it possible to remove the event from the DOM so that it cannot perform any action on the component? How can I do this?**

[image]

Comment: Can you not listen to the `onChange` event and check `EmitType<ChangedEventArgs>` == `MouseEvent` and then `event.preventDefault()`? https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/calendar/changedEventArgs/

Comment: What exactly is the `preventDefault()` function for? This allows you to select the date anyway.

Comment: You can read more about it on MDN. I'd try that as a solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: If you want to disable click in gray dates (that already have a specific css classe), you can probably do it by css too. `pointer-events: none`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use renderDayCell method to disable the required dates in syncfusion date picker component. Please check the below code block.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syz8gx?file=app.component.html

Here, we have disabled the week ends in the DatePicker popup. So, we could not select or click the dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable click event by using css somehing like this

```
/deep/.calendar {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

You need to add correct class or id of the element you want to disable click event